# How can I dynamically select a Form Control in Design Mode?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm writing a code in MS Access/VBA to change another Form from Normal Mode to Design Mode, then trying to pick a TextBox control and change it into Combobox.

The problem I'm facing now, is that I can't find a way to SetFocus to this control. In Normal Mode I can just write:

```
Form_Name.Control.SetFocus
```

But that code doesn't work when this form is in Design Mode. Is another way to Setfocus (via VBA) to this control , in another Form in Design Mode, like clicking manually in that control when editing in Design Mode?

**Edit: ** The correct would be Select the specific form control in Design Mode and not setting it focus

Comment: Focus is for receiving user input. A form in design mode cannot receive user input. You do not need to set the focus on a control in order to manipulate it programmatically.

Comment: @SunKnight0 You're right. I edited my question, I'd mean selecting the control not setting focus when in design mode

Comment: You are still too focused on trying to replicate editing the form in the same way as you would do with the GUI. You don't need to select anything to manipulate its properties with VBA. You will most likely not be able to just convert a TextBox into a ComboBox  as you would do in the GUI. That is just a GUI shortcut for deleting one control and adding another with similar properties which is what you will probably have to do.

Comment: @SunKnight0 You just opened my eyes. I didn't know that behind the scenes, changing a control type was, in fact, deleting it and creating another instead. Thank you!

Comment: If you're going to be doing this often, then instead of deleting/creating the object repeatedly, you should set .visible = true for the control you need at the specific time. Then call the correct control when needed for user input.

Answer (score 1):

You can include/exclude controls from the current selection in `Design View` by setting the `InSelection` property on each control.

The following VBA code deselects all controls and then selects the specified control:

```
Function SetSelection(frm as Form, CtlToSelect as Control)
    Dim ctl as Control

    'Deselect All Controls
    For Each ctl in frm.Controls
        ctl.InSelection = False
    Next

    'Select Specified Control
    CtlToSelect.InSelection = True
End Function
```

For more information, see the [InSelection Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa196140%28v=office.11%29.aspx) documentation on MSDN (even though this is for Access 2003, it also applies to later versions).